# Looking for an old teen horror book

Tags: story-identification

My memories are vague but I recall the basic teen girl moves to a new town but there are ruins(?) nearby for some reason. The main monster is a feathered basilisk creature from an old cave? I also remember it being venomous and that the final fight happens on the ruins. To be honest I'm almost 30 but not being able to remember this still bothers me as my kids get older and ask to read some of my old books, please help.

Comment: It you're almost 30 and you read it as a teen, that means you read it around 2000 or so? Was it in English? United States? School library? Do you remember if perhaps it was from one of the more common writers of teen horror like Christopher Pike or R.L. Stine? There is a list of questions you might consider answering at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Comment: Its in english, it wasnt an r.l.stine (im almost positive) but it was part of a series although none of the stories are linked in any way. It was from a small library with only one or two others like it. And early 2000s sounds about right.